# Behavior of pytz timezones is inconsistent

Tags: python, datetime

If I construct a Python date, and then place it in a `pytz timezone`, it behaves as expected.

```
x = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,10)
z = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
z.localize(x)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 0, tzinfo=< DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD >)
```

If I construct a Python date using a `pytz timezone` as a parameter, it does not, it is (presumably) a 'sun' time with an offset for the cities distance from the time zone border.

```
datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,10,tzinfo=tz)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 0, tzinfo=< DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' LMT-1 day, 18:09:00 STD >)
```

Is there something I can do to the date or to the timezone itself so that it behaves the same in both contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is directly in the `pytz` docs:

> > Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

Unless:

> > It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC

Which is not your case

See: http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/